# vim error E117 unknown function:ALEGetStatusLine with the plug w0rp/ale config "let g:ale_statusline_format"

Tags: vim

vim8.1, plug ale works well,but a fault blocked the status line default
this is the vimrc set:

```
let g:ale_statusline_format = ['✗ %d', '⚡ %d', '✔ OK']

set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\ [FORMAT=%{&ff}]\ [TYPE=%Y]\ [POS=%l,%v][%p%%]\ %{strftime(\"%d/%m/%y\ -\ %H:%M\")}\ %{ALEGetStatusLine()}
```

After I remove the `\ %{ALEGetStatusLine()}`, the status line works well with no any fault. But how can it work if add the ale status to my vim statusline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ALEGetStatusLine()` function [has been removed from the plugin](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/issues/1399). You're now supposed to write a custom one yourself; [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/w0rp/ale#faq-statusline) provides useful tips.

Comment: Thanks very much. I got it.  vim-airline integrates with ALE for displaying error information in the status bar. If I don't want to use vim-airline, I can implement my own statusline function without adding any other plugins.

Comment: ALE provides some functions to assist in this endeavour, including:

ale#statusline#Count: Which returns the number of problems found by ALE for a specified buffer.
ale#statusline#FirstProblem: Which returns a dictionary containing the full loclist details of the first problem of a specified type found by ALE in a buffer. (e.g. The first style warning in the current buffer.) This can be useful for displaying more detailed information such as the line number of the first problem in a file.
Say you want to display all errors as one figure, and all non-errors as another figure.

Comment: As the plugin author, I can confirm this is the right answer.